# Disable syntax highlighting for certain filenames

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, autocmd

I have syntax highlighting enabled in .vimrc, but that makes loading certain files too long. So I need to disable (or, to be precise, not enable... enabling it and then disabling is not a solution) syntax highlighting for these files. I tried

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead !*.inc syntax enable
```

but that made just no syntax highlighting applied ever. The solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496778/vim-run-autocmd-on-all-filetypes-except) does not work for me, since I can't make a distinction by filetype. I tried adapting to no avail, which might or might not be connected to the events needed for "syntax enable".

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mentioned solution points to the right direction: Define an autocmd for *all* buffers, and then (instead of `'filetype'`), match with the filename via `expand('<afile>')`:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead * if expand('<afile>:e') !=? 'inc' | syntax enable | endif
```

Here, I've used your example of `*.inc` extensions in the condition. If you find the matching cumbersome and would rather use the autocmd syntax, you can do that with an intermediate buffer flag, too, using the fact that autocmds are executed in order of definition:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.inc let b:isOmitSyntax = 1
au BufNewFile,BufRead *     if ! exists('b:isOmitSyntax') | syntax enable | endif
```

Comment: Both solutions work, thanks a lot.

Could you elaborate on the details of the matching? I get the expand part, but what does `!=?` do?

Comment: `!=?` is _does not equal, case-insensitive_; I used it since you probably don't care about the case of the file extension. As I said, the Vimscript matching is different from the pattern matching in autocmds, that's a benefit of the roundabout second solution.

Comment: Now that uou mention it, I like the case insensitivity of the first solution, so I'll keep that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to show syntax only for `.c` files. Put

```
syntax off
autocmd! bufreadpost *.c syntax on
```

in your `vimrc`.

Also you can map a key for enabling syntax (`Ctrl+s` in this case)

```
nnoremap <C-S> :syntax on<CR>
```

In you question you want to disable syntax only for `.inc` file. Do it like this:

```
syntax on
autocmd! bufreadpost *.inc set syntax=off
```

Comment: Thanks, but that would mean I'd have to readd syntax for all possible filenames I encounter but *.inc. That's exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: Thanks again, but that amounts to "enabling and then disabling" which does not solve my problem of long loading times.

Comment: Actually, this is not quite true, I tested again. I'm kinda confused about what's really happening here, but on the surface the loading times are ok. But when I manually call `:syntax on` on a *.inc file, then it's not working correctly (mainly the foldings I defined don't work).

So while this does work, it has this funky drawback I don't understand.

Comment: `Vim reads `vimrc` before loading file. Vim reads `syntax on` first and decides to highlight the syntax of file (remember it has not done any computation to color the syntax yet) then it reads second line and decides not to highlight syntax. Actually, `vim` has not done any computation at all to highlight the syntax. That is why loading times are ok. Although, I have no idea about folding issue but enabling folding after `:syntax on` may help.

Comment: Tried the last part to disable only for yml, did not work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

To disable syntax highlighting for files with .inc extension, you can basically use:

```
syntax on
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.inc setlocal syntax=OFF
```

To disable it for multiple extensions, e.g. also for py:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.{inc,py} setlocal syntax=OFF
```