# Disable syntax highlighting, but only for one filetype

Tags: vim

I want to disable syntax highlighting for a particular programming language. I'm currently using this

```
au FileType foo    syntax off
```

however this has the problem that it disables syntax highlighting for any new buffers that I open in the same window, even when they have different filetypes. Is it possible to disable syntax highlighting *only* for this filetype? (e.g. any other buffers in the same window that has different filetype should have syntax highlighting enabled)

One of the things that could solve this problem is to create a `syntax/foo.vim` file that doesn't highlight anything, but I'm not sure how to implement this when `foo` is one of the languages that vim highlights by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable syntax highlighting for certain filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440400/disable-syntax-highlighting-for-certain-filenames)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
au FileType foo setlocal syntax=OFF
```

If you want to isolate the config a bit, create a file called `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/foo.vim` and put this in it:

```
setlocal syntax=OFF
```