# Vim ignore specifc file in autocommand

Tags: git, vim

I have a vim config entry to return to the last position in a file. Is there a way to ignore git commit messages?

```
autocmd BufReadPost *
 \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
 \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
 \ endif
```

Comment: Could [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10410590/4194289) be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if expand('%:p') !~# '\m/\.git/' && line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \     exe "normal! g`\"" |
    \ endif
```