# Vim: don't remap keys in history or help buffers

Tags: vim

I have added this to my `.vimrc` in order to append a newline without leaving Normal mode:

```
nmap <Enter> o<Esc>
```

The problem is when I `q:` to the command history buffer. This binding clashes with the usage of <kbd>Enter</kbd> for selecting a command from history. A lesser problem is when reading a help page hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> will display a warning that the file is read-only. How can I remap this key in a way that ignores these two contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can undo the global mapping for the command-line window via a buffer-local mapping to itself:

```
autocmd CmdwinEnter * nnoremap <buffer> <Enter> <Enter>
```

(My [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) provides a generic `ingo#window#cmdwin#UndefineMappingForCmdwin()` function for that.)

---

For the help buffer, use the same approach, but trigger on the `FileType` event:

```
autocmd FileType help nnoremap <buffer> <Enter> <Enter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it with `autocmd` using this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/10410590/3627387

```
let blacklist = ['nofile', 'help']
autocmd FileType * if index(blacklist, &bt) < 0 | nmap <Enter> o<Esc>
```

Here we are checking for buffer type `:help 'buftype'`