# How to negate an autocmd pattern

Tags: vim

I like to trim whitespace with `autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e`, but find myself often commenting out that line in .vimrc for certain file types.  I'd like to write something like `autocmd BufWritePre !*.patch :%s/\s\+$//e` to suppress the autocmd for non-matching files, but that doesn't work.  What's a good technique for expressing the negation of a pattern match?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496778/vim-run-autocmd-on-all-filetypes-except

Comment: For a robust plugin solution (that supports exceptions) have a look at my [DeleteTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3967).